# Android emulator on Debian Jessie with GPU Emulation

Tags: android, debian, gpu

I have troubles after upgrading from Wheezy to Jessie Debian ... The ADV worked fine with Wheezy

```
$ ~/android-sdks/tools/emulator -avd MiAVD
failed to create drawable
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not create GLES 1.x Pbuffer!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebufferemulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

Of course, I need use gpu emulation, so -gpu off parameter is not an option.

Instlled gles libraries:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep gles
ii  libgles1-mesa:amd64                                         10.3.2-1                             amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 1.x API -- runtime
ii  libgles2-mesa:amd64                                         10.3.2-1                             amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- runtime
ii  mesa-utils-extra                                            8.2.0-1                              amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa utilies (opengles, egl)
```

I don't know if my Video Card is relevant information, but ... this is the output.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

More information about my configuration

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well after few weeks, I discovered the simple solution is ...

```
$ ~/android-sdks/tools/emulator -avd MiAVD -gpu mesa
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else stuck on this:

In the recommendation above -avd [Name you gave your emulator] -gpu [your value here (mine was mesa) ]

After this is done, change the emulated performance option in the profile of your emulator to software.

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try installing packages given below.

```
apt-get -y mesa-utils

apt-get -y install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5

apt-get -y install lib32stdc++6

apt-get -y install build-essential

apt-get -y install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev

apt-get -y install libgl1-mesa-dev libglfw-dev
```